# Attempt to configure failure actions of a Windows service fails with access denied error

Tags: winapi, go, service

I want to configure the failure actions for a service I have written in Go. 
I am following the answer posted at following page: 
[How do I configure failure actions of a Windows service written in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151052/how-do-i-configure-failure-actions-of-a-windows-service-written-in-go)

The function call ChangeServiceConfig2 returns "Access is denied." error in my case (when the 2nd parameter is SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS).

I am running as Administrator so I don't understand why this function gives "Access denied" error.

I can use the function ChangeServiceConfig2 to perform other actions (e.g. to set the start type for my service as Automatic Delayed, using 2nd parameter as SERVICE_CONFIG_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO).

Has anyone had similar issue when using ChangeServiceConfig2 to set failure actions for a Windows service? What is the solution in that case?

Comment: [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/2bea77d5-52e3-4683-acac-1c28b2d9109f/changeserviceconfig2-failing-with-erroraccessdenied?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues)? (And [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=ChangeServiceConfig2+failure+action+access+denied) in general).

Comment: I had already looked at the links you provided, but was unable to solve the problem. I am using CreateService and OpenProcess both with SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS access rights, and they don't give any error. I get  "access denied" when I use ChangeServiceConfig2 later for the same service.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned here: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/_McV5qokCR8

...you need to enable SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege.

Credit goes to Alex Fedotov

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this too recently. I was using SC_ACTION_RESTART as a type of action and SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG was not enough (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED). Turned out you need to open the service handle with SERVICE_START access right.